# How to use Mongoose Populate between 2 different Schema's

Tags: express, mongoose

I have 2 schema's, Categories and Cards. Each Category has an array of cards, and I want to populate that array with values , but I am unsure how to go about this as the mongoose documentation is somewhat confusing to understand.

// Schemas in seperate files
// Category Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const categorySchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    max: 30,
  },
  cards: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "categoryCard" }],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("category", categorySchema);
```

// Category Card Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const categoryCardSchema = new Schema({
  category: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  post: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("categoryCard", categoryCardSchema);
```

// Below is the express router file . I want users to be able to create cards for different categories , after the category is already created. It worked in postman, but it doesn't work on the front end for some reason.

```
router.route("/createCard").post((req, res) => {

    const { title, name, post } = req.body;

    newCard = new categoryCard({
      category: title,
      name,
      post,
    });

    newCard.save();

    category.findOne({ title }).exec((err, item) => {
      if (!err) {
        item.cards.push(newCard._id);
        item.save();
        res.send(item);
      } else {
        res.send(err);
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can Follow this code...**

```
let categorys= await category.findOne({ title }).populate("cards")
```

Comment: I'm just confused how that code works, if I haven't created the a new card yet?